# Which dependency activated a certain feature of another dependency?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

In my *binary* project, in `Cargo.toml` I have (explicitly) added a dependency `d`, but some of my other dependencies also depend on `d`. Dependency `d` has a feature `f` that is normally disabled by default, but it seems one of my other dependencies has activated that feature. How can I find out which one is that?

In `Cargo.lock` I can see multiple packages having `d` in their `dependencies` list. Also, for the package `d` itself I can see that `f` is in its `dependencies` list, but I don't see any indication as to what caused it to get there.

I could try adding/removing dependencies, to pinpoint the "culprit", but some dependencies have a deep hierarchy of dependencies, where many of those depend on `d`. So is my only option to basically browse their source code to try to see which dependency might have somehow activated `f` (directly or indirecly)? Or is there some Cargo-specific tool that could help there?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cargo tree -e features` to list all dependencies with their features.